# mongodb insert in subdocuments

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

i trying nodejs app and mongo db ,

post list

```
     post1:
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("55da3eba9ec57c443d0c2287"),
        post :  Hello i am a post
}   


     post2
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55da3db157c0bb2d3d9555c9")
        post : hello 2
}
```

and i want a new document in post1

```
      post1:
{  
         "_id" : ObjectId("55da3eba9ec57c443d0c2287"),
         post :  Hello i am a post
         comments : {
                   comment : hello i am a comment ,
                   user : req.session.user.username ,
                    }
}
```

how can i  insert or update post1

Comment: See the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator in the documentation. I also supect your representation here is incorrect and you really want an "array" of "many" comments. Therefore also see [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/). The particular "posts/comments" pattern is in fact so common, vast examples exist under [Data Modelling](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/data-modeling/) in the core documentation.

Comment: Provide code pls! When you got a model object from mongoose a subdocument list is a normal array. Push your new comment in that array and save the model instance. Thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have a collection posts on the format:

```
{
  _id:<id>,
  name: <name>,
  content: <content>,
  comments: [<comment>,...]
}
```

you can add a comment by running:

```
db.posts.update({_id: <post id>}, {$push: {comments: {comment: 'hello...', user: user}});
```